# Cambiar el estilo de un DIV cuando este sea presionado

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, framework7

### Tengo un problema con una aplicación móvil híbrida.

Quisiera cambiar el estilo de un div cuando este sea cliqueado. Actualmente tengo algo como:

```
<div id="foo">
   Lorem ipsum dolor...
</div>
```

y aplico en mi documento css:

```
#foo:active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Sin embargo, en mi aplicación móvil, cuando doy toques rápidos (**clics rápidos**) el estilo no se aplica (solo se aplica en clics largos).

¿Qué puedo hacer para que el estilo cambie al dar clics rápidos?

PD:

También he intentado usar un evento "click" con javascript, agregando y removiendo una clase con estilo diferente, sin embargo, solo funciona en el agregado de la clase y pero cuando esta se remueve no sucede nada.

css:

```
.bar{
    background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
$$('#foo').click(function(){
    $$(this).addClass('bar');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $$(this).removeClass('bar');
    }, 100);


});
```

Nota: el `$$` hace referencia a la libreria de manejo del DOM que incluye Framework7, el cual estoy utilizando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

que te parece si creas ademas del estilo de aquella clase al hacer click, alguna otra que no tenga ningun estilo o que tenga un estilo por default.

CSS:

```
.bar{
    background-color: red;
}
.no-bg{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

JS:

```
$$('#foo').click(function(){
    $$(this).removeClass('no-bg');
    $$(this).addClass('bar');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $$(this).removeClass('bar');
        $$(this).addClass('no-bg');
    }, 100);
});
```

Algo asi tal vez.

**EDICION**

El problema esta en la referencia del $(this) que haces dentro del setTimeout, deberias usar el selector o crear una variable haciendo referencia al elemento, algo asi:

```
$$('#foo').click(function(){
    $$(this).removeClass('no-bg');
    $$(this).addClass('bar');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $$('#foo').removeClass('bar');
        $$('#foo').addClass('no-bg');
    }, 100);
});
```

O asi:

```
    $$('#foo').click(function(){
        var foo = $$(this);
        foo.removeClass('no-bg');
        foo.addClass('bar');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            foo.removeClass('bar');
            foo.addClass('no-bg');
        }, 100);
    });
```

Aunque en ese caso, creo que no necesitarias tener otra clase, deberia funcionar como tenias anteriormente el codigo:

```
$$('#foo').click(function(){
    var foo = $$(this);
    foo.addClass('bar');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        foo.removeClass('bar');
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: No funcionó, visualmente solo realiza la acción programada fuera del `setTimeout`. Es muy extraño.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta dandome cuenta del posible error, pruebala

Answer (score 2):

Ten en cuenta que el evento *click* no responde igual en pantallas táctiles y esto se debe principalmente a que **existe un delay** al dispararse el evento en este tipo de pantallas. Este delay es de *300ms*, es por eso que necesitas mantener al menos 0.3 segundos para que se produzca el evento click.

HTML5 trajo, entre todas sus especificaciones, eventos táctiles como son:

- *touchstart*
- *touchend*
- *touchmove*

Estos eventos son especialmente diseñados para dispositivos móviles/táctiles, de modo que no haya delay al dispararse estos eventos.

Para corregir tu problema debes usar éstos eventos:

```
let eventName = 'click';

// usar alguna librería o una expresión regular
// para detectar si se está en dispositivo móvil
if (isMobile.any) {
  eventName = 'touchstart';
}

$('#foo').on(eventName, function() {
  $(this).addClass('bar');
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('bar');
  }.bind(this), 100);
});
```

Comment: Tu respuesta complementa la respuesta anterior, aunque, por lo que estuve leyendo, la referencia `$(this)` dentro del `setTimeout` falla debido a que esta hace referencia a `window`.

Comment: Es correcto. Hay tres opciones: guardar el contexto en una variable (el clásico self, that o _this), hacer un bind al callback del timeout y por último y la mejor de todas, usar una función flecha, ya que ignora los contextos.